# Storyboards ID not working as intended

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have 2 ViewControllers that belongs to the same class ViewController. I assigned to the second viewController the StoryBoard ID: SecondViewController but when I call it through

`[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SecondViewController"];`

I get redirected to the first ViewController and not the second one. Is there a way to fix this or I have to declare 2 different class in order for it to work?

Comment: What do you mean redirected? The object which returned by `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is kind of class first view controller?

Comment: I have a left slide menu that has a tableView with a list of all the Views on my Storyboard, if I press on the cell that leads to SecondViewController I get redirected to FirstViewController

Comment: This line `[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"SecondViewController"];` only creates view controller in memory. In order to display it you should use other methods, like `presentViewController::`

Comment: You better append more code for more detail.